# Moore's Voting Algorithm to Find Majority Element

Tags: c++

I understand that Moore's Voting algorithm to find the majority element has 2 parts -

1. First part of running Moore's Voting algorithm only gives you A candidate which occurs "most" of the time in the given array. Notice the "most" here.
2. In the second part, we need to iterate over the array once again to determine if this candidate occurs maximum number of times (i.e. greater than size/2 times).
   First iteration is to find the candidate & second iteration is to check if this element occurs majority of times in the given array.

So time complexity is: O(n) + O(n).

But I just thought instead of iterating again over the array to find if it occurs more than Array Size/2 times, cant we do something as below ?

I am using maxOcc to keep track of the current maximum element. At the end if maxOcc > size/2 then our candidate is the maximum element. This way we needn't iterate again over the entire array as per the second part of the algorithm.
Please let me know if this is good or if I am missing something?

```
void findMajorityElement()
{
    int arr[] = {10,8,8,8,8,8,8,10};
    int arrSize = 8;
    int mi = 0;
    int occ = 1;
    int maxOcc = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<arrSize-1; ++i)
    {
        if(arr[mi]==arr[i])
        {
            ++occ;
            ++maxOcc;
        }
        else
            --occ;

        if(occ == 0)
        {
            mi = i;
            occ = 1;
            maxOcc = 1;
        }
    }

    if(maxOcc > arrSize/2)
        cout <<"Majority element is "<<arr[mi]<<endl;
    else
        cout <<"Not Found!"<<endl;
}
```

This prints Majority element is 8 as it occurs 6 times.
So we save the other O(n) iteration over the array required in second step.

Kindly let me know if I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of what you call "Moore's voting algorithm" (I haven't heard of that name and I call it by the name of the inventor(s), I believe it should be called [Moore-Boyer's voting algorithm](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/)). Formally, the algorithm has `O(n+n) = O(2n) = O(n)` time complexity.

However, your modification of the algorithm fails to find a majority element for an example on a webpage I link to, i.e.: `A A A C C B B C C C B C C`:

```
int arr[] {1,1,1,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,3,3}; //A A A C C B B C C C B C C
int arrSize = 13;
```

It is because the point the algorithm is to first find **the candidate** in O(n) and then check if it is indeed a majority element, also in O(n). In order to be able to check the current element to be majority element, you would have to increase the time complexity.

Also, note that by defining the majority element the way it's defined, you are able to count the elements equal to the majority element even if there are other elements between them (e.g.: `C C B B C C C`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had checked it only for contiguous elements.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem doesn't assume that all the votes for a candidate must be contiguous: if that was the case you could just count them until the vote changes and you could even declare a winner before reading the whole array.

If the votes for a candidate are not contiguous however you should note that say after

```
AAABBBC
```

the current "candidate" has 1 good votes and is "C"; this is why the second pass is needed.

If someone has the absolute majority then it will show up as the current candidate at the end (**simple implication**).

You will always end up with a candidate at the end and but it could be someone with just one vote if there is no winner.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, It is clear to me now!